# Find the minimum two non edge, non adjacent entries in an array

Tags: algorithm

I had the following question

Find the smallest two *nonadjacent* values in an array, such that non of these elements is on the array edge (no A[0] and no A[n-1])
The runtime of the algorithm should be O(n)

I first thought about sorting the array, but sorting would cost O(nlogn)
Ignoring this fact for a second, if we sort the array, we can not just take the first two values, since they might violate the conditions mentioned above? and then what? take the next element and try, if not take the next, I can't see an easy solution there

Another solution is to generate all allowed pairs and find the pair with the minimum sum. But finding all pairs cost O(n^2)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In linear time, find the `i`th smallest entry (excluding the first and last) for `i` from 1 to 4. The best possibility is a pair of these. If 1 and 2 are nonadjacent, then that's the best. Otherwise, if 1 and 3 are nonadjacent, then that's the best. Otherwise, 2 and 3 are bordering 1 (hence not each other), and the possibilities are 1 and 4, or 2 and 3.

Comment: A cell can have 4 adjacenct cells, so you'll need the lowest 5 cells, to insure that at least one pair is non-adjacent.

Comment: @RBarryYoung I was under the impression that "no A[0] and no A[n-1]" implied a 1D array, but yes, this answer generalizes to higher dimensions.

Comment: To make sure I understand, you want to find the first 4 smallest values in the array (excluding the edges), then compare (1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(2,3),(2,4),(3,4)

Comment: @MoatazElmasry Essentially, yes (some of those combinations are never profitable, but their inclusion doesn't matter).

Comment: I think your solution would work also with smallest 3 elements instead of 4. I cannot think of an example input where this won't work with 3 smallest values

Comment: @MoatazElmasry How about 10 5 3 1 4 11?

Answer (score 0):

You could go with your sort first, then, unless I am missing something, take elements 0 and 2. Those would be the smallest non-adjacent values.

As long as the array is 3 elements or greater you should be assured that the element values in position 0 and 2 are the smallest (and if you need them to be, non-consecutive) as well as non-adjacent in the array.

Comment: Yes but I want to find the two smallest elements in the non sorted array, meaning that even after sorting the array we need to find those elements in the non sorted one

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question. Yes you would need to iterate through your first array to find the index of the values which are smallest in the sorted. Most languages support an .indexOf(value) method on arrays.

Answer (score 0):

If your array is sorted, you would only have to keep comparing alternate elements (like indices (0,2), (1,3), (2,5)) and so on and then find the pair with the smallest difference. But without sorting, you are right in saying that the run time complexity would then become O(n^2) as you would have to compare every element with every other element in the array.

Comment: Even after sorting, you will have to compare (1,2), (1,3).. (1,n-2), then (2,3), ...(n-4, n-2). Again this is O(n^2)